# Is the person in this video any relation to Ian Nepomniachtchi?

Tags: famous-players

Towards the very end of this video that shows a talk or lecture by Mikhail Tal from 1988:

https://youtu.be/5bb6e0gFdS4

during question and answer time from the audience, someone introduces himself as "Nepomnyaschiy, engineer".  It's at about the 1:13:30 mark of the video.

Is this possibly some relation to Ian Nepomniachtchi, or is it just a coincidence?  (I'm assuming the name is an English phonetic transliteration, and could be spelled either way...)

I just happened to see this and was surprised, as I've never heard of anyone with that name before (then again, I don't live in or near Russia, so that might be why - not sure how common the name is...), and thought I'd ask about it just because it's an interesting question....

Comment: Seems very unlikely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Family name Непомнящий (*Nepomnyashchy* or however you spell it in English) is of course not one of the most common in Russia but it is definitely not one of the rarest.
There are about 20 more or less promiment persons with this name on [Russian Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9). So it is very unlikely that the person in Youtube video is somehow related to Ian Nepomnyashchy.